# Не получается сделать обратный таймер с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Использовал команду:

ffmpeg -y -i inp.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='Fonts/arial.ttf':fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:x=(main_w/2-text_w/2):y=(main_h/2-text_h/2):text='%{eif:trunc(mod(((14-t)/60),60)):d:2}:%{eif:trunc(mod(14-t,60)):d:2}':box=1:boxborderw=2:boxcolor=0x00000099:enable='between(t,0,14)'" timer.mp4

Но в итоге выводится только:"trunc(mod(((14-t)/60),60)):d:2}:trunc(mod(14-t,60)):d:2"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130904/15035314